# Ecommerce database design related products

Tags: database, e-commerce

I'm building an e-commerce site. I have a products table in database but wish to also include Related Products and Recommended Products. Expect to output several Related Products and Recommended Product on each product page. How to set up database - separate "Related" and "Recommended" tables linked to the product table by Product Id?

Answer (score 0):

Create two new tables:

1. `RelatedProduct`, which contains at least `ProductId` and `RelatedProductId`
2. `RecommendedProduct`, which contains  at least `ProductId` and `RecommendedProductId`